# Adding object to initialized @array

Tags: arrays, ruby, push, instance

I am trying to create an array of Country objects. I have checked every part of the code and so far the only one that doesn't work is the actual adding of the Country object into an array.
Can someone help me understand why
    `array << object`
doesn't work? The entire code can be found here http://pastebin.com/jNyJvS3c and the problem part in question is at line 23.

Comment: You can paste your code in your question and use code formatting to highlight them as code

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code `country.nil? {@countries << country};`, the code within `{...}` is being treated as block and not getting executed.  Below are corrections

Below are those functions with corrections suggested:

```
  def add_country(country)
    @countries << country unless country.nil?
  end

  def to_s(n)
    string = ""
    for i in 0..n do
      string << @countries[i].to_s unless @countries[i].nil?
    end
    return string
  end
```

Comment: omgg Thank you so much! I literally had the lecture on blocks on last Friday and already forgot x( But thank you :)  
Also this unless syntax I think will be very useful so it's good to know that I can place it in the end rather than the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0):

In line 23 you actually pass a block to nil? method. This block {@countries << country} is never called as method nil? doesn't expect a block.

So the right way doing what you need:

```
def add_country(country)
  @countries << country unless country.nil?
end
```